# How to read server response (JSON) for file upload in Android?

Tags: java, android, file-upload

I have this code that uploads a file to our server (PHP). How do I read the server's output not just the code 200 or "ok" but the actual JSON response?

I've seen examples using InputStreamReader and BufferedReader but I'm not sure how to use them...

```
public String uploadFile(){     
    String result = "Result:";
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;

    String pathToOurFile = "/storage/emulated/0/My Documents/My Recordings/Voice0007.aac";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024*1024;

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

        URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Set HTTP method to POST.
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0){
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        //inputStream = (DataInputStream) connection.getInputStream();

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        // doesn't show the JSON respnse :(
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage(); 

        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("Test", line);
        }
        bufferReader.close();                    

        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        result = serverResponseCode + "-"+ serverResponseMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = "exception: "+(ex.getStackTrace().toString()) + "\n" + ex.toString();

    }finally{
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

The JSON you are looking for gets written in the HTTP-responses [Entity Body](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html).

To get it you need to obtain the Connections InputStream and read it like this:

```
InputStream in;
try {
    in = connection.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, read, "utf-8"));
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Worked for me.. thanks!!! I am making an edit to this answer, hope it help others too.